# Can this be done without functions and procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, datediff

I have been given something to think on, and could not come up with an answer. Let us look at 'the' employees sample database ([employees schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/images/employees-schema.png)). My task is, to find the longest period in which no-one had his/her salary modified, that is: I need to find the from_date attribute from record, where the difference between it and the succeeding record's from_date attribute is maximal amongst other similar (record, succeeding record) attribute tuples. My question is: can this be accomplished without the use of stored-procedures and functions? I was told this should be a hard-one, but it is a really a simple maximum selection if a function is used - or is it not? I am using MySQL 5.1. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

maybe not the most efficient, but

```
SELECT TOP 1
datediff(s1.from_date
    ,(select top 1 s2.from_date from salaries s2 
      where s2.from_date > s1.from_date order by s2.from_date))
       AS daysSinceChange
FROM salaries s1
ORDER BY daysSinceChange DESC
```

Comment: +1 I had to add a 'day' first parameter to get it to work in t-sql - does mysql not require a unit parameter?

Comment: that's funny, because I tested it on sql server, and had the day parameter in there. I looked up datediff for mysql and it said it only took the two parameters, so I removed the day parameter from my answer since the question had the mysql tag.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me, my question was a genuine question, not an attempt to suggest you were wrong!  Without checking I didn't realise that t-sql was simply more advanced.  MySql differences in days only, Oracle is worse, it stores dates as numbers so you can do date1 - date2 and then round to get the day difference.

Comment: no, I meant funny as in a chuckle. I had to put effort into checking into the differences and then changing my original code, then you had to do the same effort in reverse, all because of these annoying incompatibilities.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for the answers! Unfortunately I could not make the query work. I shall respond and give feedback, once I managed to 1. understand and 2. try  it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about dates, but for ints...

```
  Select max(sub.x - tbl.x)
    From table_name tbl,
         (Select min(tbl2.x) x
            From table_name tbl2
           Where (matches outer record)
             And tbl2.x >= tbl.x) sub;
```

Basically, select the maximum difference of x and y where y is the minimum date corresponding to the same user but with value greater than the one it's being compared to. If this is legal, something along these lines should work.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your tip. I will interpret it and try to implement it for dates to see how it comes out!